# How do you compute the 90% percentile height (Z) in PDAL?

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds, pdal

How can you use filters to compute the height (Z) of the point in a point view that is higher than 90% of the other points using PDAL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use pdal's [filters.python](https://pdal.io/stages/filters.python.html#filters-python). In the filter use numpy.percentile to filter for the 90% percentile.

Comment: Could you please share a snippet of code how to achieve that and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Will do when the python filters are working in conda again. Currently there seems to be a bug but adding a code snippet is on my agenda!